how to recreate these timing tables in lyx?
i've got the following time tables which i tried to make using tables and playing with the borders but it doesn't compile well

and here's what I did in LyX with the table and borders:

but this is the compiled output using xeTex:

here's the code for my table from LyX:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}{|ccccccc|c|c|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{$\text{D-Latch}$}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multirow{2}{*}{1} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\text{E}$}\tabularnewline
\cline{5-7}
 &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{8-8}
 &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  & \multirow{2}{*}{0} & \tabularnewline
\cline{6-7}\cline{1-2}
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{8-9}
 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multirow{2}{*}{1} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\text{D}$}\tabularnewline
\cline{5-6}\cline{1-3}
 &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{8-8}
 &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{0} & \tabularnewline
\cline{7-7}\cline{4-4}
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{8-9}
 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multirow{2}{*}{1} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\text{Q}$}\tabularnewline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\cline{8-8}
 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multirow{2}{*}{0} & \tabularnewline
\cline{7-7}
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


I suggest to abandon the table approach and spend some time on this package: https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-timing . And yes, you’ll need the evil red …

@MS-SPO oh dang, i was trying to avoid it haha, well there goes another hour or two of my life to learn another package, thanks

You‘ll make. If you look for examples, e.g. this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512778/negative-amplitude-signals-on-tikz-timing-return-to-zero, which is amongst results from following https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-timing .

If you would like to keep the table approach, you could use tabularray:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={*9{c}},
  columns={wd=.3cm},
  vline{4-Y}={dashed},
  vline{1-3,Z}={solid},
  vline{4,6,7}={7-8}{solid,wd=1pt},
  vline{5,8}={3-4}{solid,wd=1pt},
  hline{1,2,Z}={solid},
  hline{2}={2}{-}{solid},
  hline{3}={5-7}{solid,wd=1pt},
  hline{4,8,12}={2}{solid},
  hline{5}={3-4,8-Z}{solid,wd=1pt},
  hline{6,10}={1-2}{solid},
  hline{7}={4-5,7-Z}{solid,wd=1pt},
  hline{9}={3,6}{solid,wd=1pt},
  hline{13}={3}{solid,wd=1pt},
  }
\SetCell[c=9]{c} D-Latch\\
\SetCell[r=4]{} E & \SetCell[r=2]{} 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
 &  & {} &  &  & {} &  &  & \\
 & \SetCell[r=2]{}{0} & {} &  &  & {} &  &  & \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\SetCell[r=4]{} D & \SetCell[r=2]{} 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\
 &  &  & {} & {} &  & {} &  & \\
 & \SetCell[r=2]{} 0 &  & {} & {} &  & {} &  & \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\SetCell[r=4]{} Q & \SetCell[r=2]{} 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
 & \SetCell[r=2]{} 0 &  &  &  &  &  & & \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}


To use it in LyX, you should add:
\usepackage{tabularray}

in your LyX preamble, and then add the code of the table as ERT:
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={*9{c}},
  columns={wd=.3cm},
  vline{4-Y}={dashed},
  vline{1-3,Z}={solid},
  vline{4,6,7}={7-8}{solid,wd=1pt},
  vline{5,8}={3-4}{solid,wd=1pt},
  hline{1,2,Z}={solid},
  hline{2}={2}{-}{solid},
  hline{3}={5-7}{solid,wd=1pt},
  hline{4,8,12}={2}{solid},
  hline{5}={3-4,8-Z}{solid,wd=1pt},
  hline{6,10}={1-2}{solid},
  hline{7}={4-5,7-Z}{solid,wd=1pt},
  hline{9}={3,6}{solid,wd=1pt},
  hline{13}={3}{solid,wd=1pt},
  }
\SetCell[c=9]{c} D-Latch\\
\SetCell[r=4]{} E & \SetCell[r=2]{} 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
 &  & {} &  &  & {} &  &  & \\
 & \SetCell[r=2]{}{0} & {} &  &  & {} &  &  & \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\SetCell[r=4]{} D & \SetCell[r=2]{} 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &\\
 &  &  & {} & {} &  & {} &  & \\
 & \SetCell[r=2]{} 0 &  & {} & {} &  & {} &  & \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\SetCell[r=4]{} Q & \SetCell[r=2]{} 1 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
 & \SetCell[r=2]{} 0 &  &  &  &  &  & & \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
\end{tblr}


Here is one way to do it without LyX. I.e. in your LaTeX view from Lyx your code should look very similar in the preamble, while the parts from the documents would be entered without the GUI, i.e. via the evil red ...
Some remarks.

The first part just shows 3 tikztimingtables in running text. Kindly watch the alignment with the basline(s), and the vertical spacings introduced, here via \bigskip. Basically you can see the tikztimingtable in action.

The second part uses a floating table, i.e. LaTeX finds "the best place" for it itself. At its heart there is a tabular table. As an ordinary table it would look like this:
 \begin{tabular}{lcr}       % just a table
  D-latch   & NAND       & NOR\\    % syntax
  some text & other text & more text\\
 \end{tabular}

However, to place tikztimingtable environments as elements, just put them inside curly braces { }. So the tables structure reads like this:
 \begin{tabular}{lcr}       % just a table
  D-latch   & NAND       & NOR\\    % syntax
  {.}       & {.}        & {.}\\
 \end{tabular}

where the . denotes the three tikztimingtable environments.

For demonstration purposes I used \begin{tabular}{lcr} (l, c and r) to show the effect of alignment in this approach.

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

D-latch:
 \begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/draw grid,scale=2]
    E   & llhhhll \\
    D   & lhhlhhh \\
    Q   & lzzzzzz \\
 \end{tikztimingtable}
 \bigskip

NAND:
 \begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/draw grid,scale=2]
    S   & hllhhh \\
    R   & hhhhlh \\
    Q   & lzzzzz \\
 \end{tikztimingtable}
 \bigskip

NOR:
 \begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/draw grid,scale=2]
    S   & llhlll \\
    R   & llllhl \\
    Q   & lzzzzz \\
 \end{tikztimingtable}
 \bigskip\hrule\bigskip
 
\begin{table}[b]            % floating environment: LaTeX finds best place
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{lcr}       % just a table
  D-latch   & NAND  & NOR\\ % syntax
  \\                        % insert an empty line
  {\begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/draw grid,scale=3]
    E   & llhhhll \\
    D   & lhhlhhh \\
    Q   & lzzzzzz \\
  \end{tikztimingtable}} &  % 1st element isn't text, but a timing-table
  { \begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/draw grid,scale=3]
    S   & hllhhh \\
    R   & hhhhlh \\
    Q   & lzzzzz \\
  \end{tikztimingtable}}&   % 2nd element isn't text, but a timing-table
  { \begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/draw grid,scale=3]
    S   & llhlll \\
    R   & llllhl \\
    Q   & lzzzzz \\
  \end{tikztimingtable}}\\  % 3rd element AND break \\
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Timing diagrams}
\end{table} 

\end{document}

